# Why is this v2.7 rigged low-poly model slugglish in the Blender 3.0 viewport?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I purchased a rigged low-poly model created in Blender 2.7 (the file is 8 years old) and when I try to move it or rescale it in the Blender 3.0 viewport it is extremely slow to respond. When I try to manipulate it, it's as though it's choking my PC, but my PC is new and very capable. Something to do with the rigging maybe? Am I missing something basic? Thanks. Blender 3.01, Windows 11

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the .blend file with us? To check anything out of the ordinary about it.

Comment: @Throndronis Thank you for the response. I can't share the blend file because I purchased it from a 3rd-party.

Comment: maybe the mesh is high-poly? in that case it makes any animation very tedious

Comment: @moonboots Is the mesh high-poly? Good question. Surprise! According to Scene statistics, a Blender scene with just the rigged model alone is 418k vertices and 833k triangles, while the Collada (unrigged) version of the model is just 2k vertices and 3.5k triangles. Okay, something wacky about how Blender 3 is handling a version 2.7 armature?

Comment: I don't know why it came from 2k to 418k, it should not have anything to do with the armature

Comment: @moonboots I don't know anything about rigging, so it's a mystery to me. The file size is only 12k, however if I convert the object to mesh and delete the rigging, the file size jumps to 130k and Edit Mode reveals a model that's changed from a few to a zillion vertices.

Comment: When you say that you converted the object to mesh, what was it before?

Comment: @moonboots I don't know what it was before. Looked like a normal mesh to me. The workflow that's working for me now is 1) Create pose; 2) RMB > Convert to > Mesh; 3) delete armature; 4) Edit Mode > Mesh > Clean Up > Decimate Geometry, ratio = 0.01.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing all this, maybe go back to the original file and show how the mesh looks like

Comment: @moonboots I just posted a screenshot of views in Object & Edit modes. I'm going through all this to get me a model that I can append into my other projects. There's surely a better way, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: what you show is the difference between Object and Edit mode face number, but in Object mode it also counts the other objects of your file while in Edit mode it only counts the faces of the selected object. If the topology you show is the current one, it is ok in terms of face number, so I'm not sure why the animation is so slow, hard to tell

Comment: @moonboots There are only 3 objects in the file: the astronaut aka "cube.000", 3k vertices; the visor, 280 vertices; and the armature. That's why I was thinking the armature accounted for the remaining 800k vertices.

Comment: An armature is not a mesh so will have few vertices; something like two for every bone (one at each end of a bone), of which there are generally not many many bones.  One thing I have done when sharing proprietary blend files is to try and edit the mesh and delete many vertices (like the whole top half of the character mesh), so it becomes unusable to anyone else as a complete character.... So long as the general problem persists in the reduced example file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual culprits for low performance imported models, in my experience:

- Subdivision Surface modifier: This is supposed to be fixed in the near future, but using subdivision surface modifiers on armatures, at least in the viewport, can be slow and fiddly.
- File hasn't been told to use your hardware for Render views: Preferences for Cycles/EEVEE and the render device are per-machine/per-file, so remember to use the GPU if you have one up to the task.
- Poor modifier order: having the Bevel modifier BEFORE the armature, and orderings like this, can send your computer into fits.  Some modifiers assume they are working on relatively low polys (like armature, bevel, boolean), so if they are after modifiers that add a lot of geometry, that will cause problems.
- Material Deformation:  It might have got/ been made better, but materials that use the deformation output tend to slow my machine down.

Comment: Yep, the Multires modifier was the culprit. Never run into this before. Thank you!